# Approach for n-tier CRUD applications in .NET

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, n-tier-architecture, crud

Here’s a really really super-basic question.

Say I wanted to build – today – an enterprise CRUD application in .NET that had an n-tier architecture.  What data access approach should I use?  I want interoperability, so DataSets are out (and I suppose it’s not 2003 anymore, either).  Likewise, .NET RIA Services’ advertised method of exposing its functions, via an additional service, to non-Silverlight clients, doesn’t seem very [convincing](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/07/31/business-apps-example-for-silverlight-3-rtm-and-net-ria-services-july-update-part-xx-exposing-a-wcf-service.aspx) for update operations.  I’ve *sort of* been able to cobble together something with Entity Framework, which doesn’t have n-tier support OOB and so required lots of weird reflection-type stuff to simulate the semblance of optimistic concurrency (the [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee321569.aspx) in MSDN Magazine doesn’t look like it supports optimistic concurrency.  I [hear](http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/archive/2009/03/24/self-tracking-entities-in-the-entity-framework.aspx) this is improved in EF4, but I’m a little bit skeptical and it’s not really available yet besides in CTP).

So, what can people actually do on their projects for enterprise CRUD with update-checked optimistic concurrency?  DataSets?  DIY with DTOs and Lord knows how much work involved?  And how does that work with bound data?  Say I have a collection bound to a DataGrid, do I need to listen to CollectionChanged for changes?  Do I need to keep stacks of changes so I can compare PKs if there’s an undo?  It seems nightmarish.

And, secondarily, what if update checking for optimistic concurrency weren’t a hard requirement?  What then?

Comment: How big is the app?  How long will it be in service for?  How many users?  One location or multiple?  What is the current experience and knowledge base of the developers? You say you want interoperability, but with what? 
Choosing technology solutions without this context is pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, if you plan to move to VS2010 and .NET 4.0 in the future, I highly recommend looking into EF v4.0. It has improved DRAMATICALLY since EF v1.0 was released, and is, in my opinion, a strong contender against the likes of nHibernate and friends. EF is the central player in a lot of Microsofts future data initiatives as well, so it can't really be ignored as easily as it used to be. It, or any of the .NET 4.0 higher level frameworks that depend on it, should serve your CRUD needs well.

That aside, I would just make sure that a simple CRUD approach is the best fit from a **business perspective**. CRUD makes a ton of sense from a technical perspective, and in smaller applications, it is usually the right choice. But you used the term 'enterprise', so I am curious if your application has a broader scope than the simplicity CRUD serves well.

Anything beyond your small-scale company with 20-50 or so employees total, and I would look into Domain Driven Design (DDD) and SOA. If you need things like concurrency management and things like that, the principals that drive DDD should serve you well. SOA is generally useful for extremely large projects where you have many development teams concurrently working on multiple projects that need to interact with each other. It may be overkill for your needs, but there are some good principals that may still help.

Comment: Thanks much.  This is a large and complex application that will scale to at least hundreds of users.  Let me be clear - when I say n-tier CRUD, I mean including SOA here.  My question is really about change tracking.  So I want to have my WCF service expose operations - which have either simple or complex semantics - for my client to call.  The way I see it, I have two choices: interoperable, platform specific DTOs, or some .NET specific technology (like EF) that may or may not have change tracking built in for updates.

It seems the second solution could be *much* less work.  Thoughts?

Comment: Entity Framework v4.0 does have a full multi-tier change tracking solution. They actually developed an open specification for transferring change tracking information across the wire, so if you use non-.NET clients, they would still be compatible. In addition, they provided full support for custom change tracking, if needed. Like I mentioned before, EF v4.0 (not v1.0) is a SERIOUS contender for the ORM crown now. If change tracking is your prime concern, you should really check out EF: http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/

Comment: Thanks.  Follow-up question: what would you do if .NET 4.0 were off the table, and you were restricted to .NET 3.5 SP1 libraries?  What choice would you make then?

Comment: I would use nHibernate. It is not nearly as rich and convenient as EF v4.0, but it has most of the same capabilities. It is a little less capable in the n-tier, SOA change tracking arena...you would probably have to roll your own implementation. But nHibernate is a very rich, seasoned ORM that is well-vetted by the community. If you are willing to spend some money, LLBLGen offers better n-tier change tracking, but...it costs money.